# Setup self signed SSL on Mac OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I'm trying to setup a self signed SSL certificate with [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/internet/serverside/modssl.html), but I'm getting these errors at the last step of certificate creation (with the sign.sh script) `error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate` and `error 7 at 0 depth lookup:certificate signature failure`.

What should I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

I've setup built-in OS X Apache with HTTPS/SSL a few times. Here's a wiki guide we wrote up documenting it. It is much simpler than the method in the tutorial you cited

Configure Apache for SSL in OS X Snow Leopard:

https://apps.education.ucsb.edu/wiki/Enable_HTTPS_in_Snow_Leopard%27s_Apache

Create a Self-Signed SSL cert with a one-liner:

https://apps.education.ucsb.edu/wiki/Create_a_self-signed_SSL_certificate

Comment: +1 because that's my wiki! Oh wait. You're Cocoabean. I feel less cool because I know you. But so you know, I was just checking the logs and this page is generating traffic to the wiki, so even though you're not getting upvotes, you are helping. :)